# Access parent variable from child component template

Tags: angular

I have two classes, `Secure` and `Client`. My `Secure` class is a parent of `Client`.

The idea is that when a class extends `Secure`, the constructor checks authentication and redirects to a login page if the user is not authenticated. The class looks like this:

```
export class Secure {

    protected user: User;

    constructor(public router: Router, public userHandler: UserHandler) {
        userHandler.checkAuthentication(this);
    }

    isLoggedIn(message: string, isLoggedIn: boolean) {
        if(!isLoggedIn){
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
    }

    getUser(): User{
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

And my child-class looks like this:

```
export class ClientsComponent extends Secure{

  client: Client = new Client();

  clients: Array<Client>;

  constructor(public router: Router, public userHandler: UserHandler, public clientService: ClientService) {
      super(router, userHandler);

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getAllUsers(this);
  }

  doRegister(){
      this.clientService.createNewClient(this.client.email, this);
  }

  callbackRegisterComplete(){
    this.clientService.getAllUsers(this);
  }

  callbackWithClients(clients:Array<Client>){
    this.clients = clients;
  }

}
```

In my `Clients` template I would like to check if the user in my `Secure`class got a certain role:

```
<tr *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index">
    <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
    <td>{{client.email}}</td>
    <td>{{client.userStatus}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="user.isAdmin">...</td>
</tr>
```

But this produces the following error: *Cannot read property 'isAdmin' of undefined*

So my question is: Is there any way to access a variable in a parent class from the child class template? If not, is there any good ways to work around this?

Comment: Are these components or just classes?

Comment: Both are components @Chrillewoodz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of extending, simply use `@Input()` to pass data from a parent component to a child component:

`parent` template:

```
<child [someData]="data"></child>
```

This is the most efficient way to share data across components.

Now in `child` you can grab the data via `this.someData` or `someData` if you want it from the template.

Answer (score 2):

If your child component is strictly related only to its parent then you can use inheritance.

Just extend from parent and you'll have everything that parent has in your child component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'task',
  template: `<task-body></task-body>`,
})
export class TaskComponent{
   taskType:any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'task-body',
  template: `Here you can see variable from parent {{taskType}}`,
})
export class TaskBodyComponent extends TaskComponent{
   //also you can use parent variable in your child component as that 
    variable would exist on your child
   logSomething(){
      console.log(this.taskType);
   }
}
```